# Who sent the Luca Android to replace Luca?

Tags: bodacious-space-pirates

When it's found out that for quite a while, Luca was actually an Android who had been transmitting information out of the Bentenmaru almost right after Luca appears and reveals she was on vacation the entire time, yet she doesn't say if she had sent the android to replace her.

So, I'm wondering, who sent the android? And if it wasn't Luca, how did they know when she went on vacation?

Comment: It's the word of the Grand Cross.

Comment: I would say it is impossible to answer, as the whole arc is anime original.